# How dynamically creates Popup in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

When I try to dynamically creates Popup with *Qt.createQmlObject(...)* or *Qt.createComponent(...)*, I got exception:

> QML Popup: cannot find any window to open popup in.

Here is my code:

```
var popup1 = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.8; import QtQuick.Controls 2.1; Popup { id: popup; x: 100; y: 100; width: 200; height: 300; modal: true; focus: true; closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent; visible: false }',
                                window,
                                "DynamicPopup");
popup1.open()

var popupComponent = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/TestPopup.qml")
var popup2 = popupComponent.createObject(window);
popup2.open()
```

TestPopup.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Popup {
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
    modal: true
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
    visible: false
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Popup` is not inheriting `QQuickItem`, and by default it is parented by `QML Window`, which is not instantiated if you are using `QQuickWidget`. Thus passing `parent` should be done as follows:

```
var popupComponent = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/TestPopup.qml")
var popup2 = popupComponent.createObject(window, {"parent" : window});
popup2.open()
```

Comment: @A.J, what is `window` in your example? Try to bind `Popup` to `QQuickItem`

Comment: Well, my window is an ApplicationWindow. Thank you very much.

Comment: The solution works for me, but it seems <code>{"parent": window}</code> is not required. When I specify it, I will get the error "Error: Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem*", the error will disappear when I remove the second argument. My Qt version is 6.3.1.

Answer (score 5):

The parent must be an element that inherits from `QQuickItem`

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Window {
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Row{
        Button{
            id: item1
            text: "btn1"
            onClicked: {
                var popup1 = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.8; import QtQuick.Controls 2.1; Popup { id: popup; x: 100; y: 100; width: 200; height: 300; modal: true; focus: true; closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent; visible: false }',
                                                item1,
                                                "DynamicPopup");
                popup1.open()

            }
        }

        Button{
            id: item2
            text: "btn2"
            onClicked: {
                var popupComponent = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/TestPopup.qml")
                var popup2 = popupComponent.createObject(item2);
                popup2.open()
            }

        }

    }
}
```

method 1:

[image]

method 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `Popup` needs to be be parented to an `Item`, `window` isn't one.
You should use [`window.contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentItem-prop) instead.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to dynamically load a popup with a Loader:

```
Loader {
    id: popupLoader

    active: false
    source: "qrc:/TestPopup.qml"
    onLoaded: item.open()
}

function openMyPopup() {
    if( popupLoader.active )
        popupLoader.item.open()
    else
        popupLoader.active = true
}
```